# How to export and then import the keys to decryption?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to use RSA module in python to encrypt and decrypt strings. In the documentation it says you can import the keys by using

```
with open('private.pem', mode='rb') as privatefile:
    keydata = privatefile.read()
privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata)
```

But how can we export the newly generated keys?
Also, where should I save both the private and public key? Should I keep it in different databases and import it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already implemented the import. For the export you can simply use `save_pkcs1()`, e.g.

```
import rsa

(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512) # 512 only for testing purposes, otherwise at least 2048

# PEM (default)
print(privkey.save_pkcs1().decode('utf-8'))
print(pubkey.save_pkcs1().decode('utf-8'))

# DER
print(privkey.save_pkcs1('DER').hex())
print(pubkey.save_pkcs1('DER').hex())
```

with e.g. the following output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBPQIBAAJBAJ4hEw3nvXbdK4OAEMeGZ3+jb37GChxkzCaqoFtrexiIl70Nq5Dc
oxqEqxDpXGkkK5WNa5qzimVwKKbiSChEyIsCAwEAAQJAGp7kz015Jv6a6btwl7Z3
zBQenBAI+bi6abQF5P4WDTuKlgt6K1YaFDpdIbp4gmiqFmdhyUvyd3aylHprERv9
WQIjAML4S/aqlQS/06DFOy9UOHMgoXv/P6I9uCHJbd6Rr0dLlHUCHwDPoJZE60Po
As0ae7fNXzIX5quYMM60Kcg42QXvSP8CIwChWxiTFe2qNo+QeGpY6xykuxaqJj6l
qOqgm7GgB3XGTViZAh4Bv7CEVBb2VU+08WXS7QJXATJgzchv7AorsGhEY7ECIwCy
zqoZ402jQJ0l0lIXAIzqSApotwz3Rpr0DT87hNIU8MHg
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MEgCQQCeIRMN57123SuDgBDHhmd/o29+xgocZMwmqqBba3sYiJe9DauQ3KMahKsQ
6VxpJCuVjWuas4plcCim4kgoRMiLAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

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
30480241009e21130de7bd76dd2b838010c786677fa36f7ec60a1c64cc26aaa05b6b7b188897bd0dab90dca31a84ab10e95c69242b958d6b9ab38a657028a6e2482844c88b0203010001
```

see also the [tests](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/blob/main/tests/test_pem.py) in the source code.

The key can then be stored in a file if required.

Regarding your questions about securing the keys: The private key must be kept secret. This is not so easy. There are many posts on how to do this, e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/how-to-store-a-private-rsa-key-for-an-application) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220950/where-to-store-the-private-key).